# How to select multiple rows with only one tag row

Tags: sql, sql-server

Table A

```
  RowID |       A      |        B       |  C 
 -------+--------------+----------------+---- 
      1 |  google.com  |  search engine |  1 
      2 |  google.com  |                |    
      3 |  google.com  |                |    
      4 |  google.com  |                |    
      6 |  dropbox.com |  consumer      |  1 
      7 |  dropbox.com |                |    
      8 |  dropbox.com |                |    
      9 |  dropbox.com |                |    
     10 |  dropbox.com |                |
```

How to select row 1 to 4 where column c = 1?

Query below

```
select * 
from tableA 
where C = '1'
```

Comment: What exactly is the output you want?

Comment: You need more criteria to be able to select the rows 1-4, for example consider where A='google.com' with this the query would be:    select * from tableA where C = '1' and A='google.com'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Despite there're better ways to collect data, if I understood well what you're trying to achieve, this should work on many situation:

```
DECLARE @t table (RowID  int, A varchar(50), B varchar(50), C int)
DECLARE @MaxId int

INSERT INTO @t(RowID,A,B,C)
VALUES  (1,'google.com','search engine',1),
        (2,'google.com',NULL,NULL),
        (3,'google.com',NULL,NULL),
        (4,'google.com',NULL,NULL),
        (6,'dropbox.com','consumer',1),
        (7,'dropbox.com',NULL,NULL),
        (8,'dropbox.com',NULL,NULL),
        (9,'dropbox.com',NULL,NULL),
        (10,'dropbox.com',NULL,NULL)

SELECT @MaxId = MAX(RowID)
  FROM @t

SELECT T.RowID, T.A, I.B
  FROM @t AS T
LEFT JOIN (SELECT RowID, B, ISNULL(LEAD(RowId) OVER (ORDER BY RowId) - 1,@MaxId) AS LastId
             FROM @t
            WHERE C = 1) AS I
    ON T.RowID BETWEEN I.RowID AND I.LastId
WHERE I.B = 'search engine'
```

In this case the search criteria is on column B. I expect that real data has different values on column A for the same set of data (i.e. 'search engine'). For Example this solution works also on this dataset:

```
  RowID |       A          |        B       |  C 
 -------+------------------+----------------+---- 
      1 |  google.com      |  search engine |  1 
      2 |  bing.com        |                |    
      3 |  duckduckgo.com  |                |    
      4 |  google.co.uk    |                |    
      6 |  dropbox.com     |  consumer      |  1 
      7 |  facebook.com    |                |    
      8 |  instagram.com   |                |    
      9 |  onedrive.com    |                |    
     10 |  wikipedia.com   |                |
```

Of course we're talking about sample, unreal data. Real data should be more complex, and I expect more columns, but it's just matter of adding them to the SELECT.

Answer (score 0):

If column C is an integer then  use

```
select * 
from tableA 
where C = 1
```

if is a string  then be sure you have  not hidden char

```
select * 
from tableA 
where trim(C) = '1'
```

Answer (score 0):

row 1-4 do you want the o/p as of `google.com` then add one more condition to your where clause as

```
 select * 
  from tableA 
   where C = '1' and A like 
      '%google.com%'
```

or if you want on basis of B only then

```
   select * 
  from tableA 
   where C = '1' and B like 
      '%search engine%'
```

Answer (score 0):

first you select row where column `C` value is `1`

```
SELECT *
FROM   tableA a
WHERE  a.C = '1'
```

from there you can `JOIN` back to your table to get the rest of the rows based on `A`

```
SELECT a2.*
FROM   tableA a
       INNER JOIN tableA a2  ON a.A = a2.A
WHERE  a.C = '1'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLEA
WHERE A IN
(
SELECT A
FROM TABLEA
WHERE C = 1
)
```

Regards